# Inject dependencies inside MassTransit consumer

Tags: .net-core, masstransit

```
public class CreatePersonHandler : IConsumer<CreatePerson>
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public CreatePersonHandler(IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<CreatePerson> context)
        {
            ...
            Person person = _mapper.Map<Person>(context.Message);
            _unitOfWork.Persons.Add(person);
        }
    }
```

In my other service inside Program Main method I'm trying to register this consumer CreatePersonHandler
...

```
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.Host(...);
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("persons", x =>
                {
                    ...
                    x.ConfigureConsumer<CreatePerson>(); // how to inject dependencies here?
                });
            });
    var cancToken = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
    await bus.StartAsync(cancToken);
    ...
```

I cannot configure consumer on line `e.ConfigureConsumer<CreatePerson>()` because I need to inject `IUnitOfWork` and `IMapper`. How to do this from here?   If I remove dependencies from the consumer the solution compiles and run without error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the proper configuration for MassTransit:

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<CreatePersonHandler>();

    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) => cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context));
});
```

Then, just make sure your dependencies are registered in the container. For example:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

You can [read the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/configuration.html#consumers) for more details.